# STRCHR vs STRRCHR difference?

Tags: php, string, strchr, strrchr

I would like to know the difference between the two different uses. 
I believe the difference in some what very subtle.

This is an explanation taken from the IBM reference manual.
However maybe my english is bad, I just can't visualize the difference.

Maybe showing me an example of both cases would help me understand this better.

Here is the explanation from IBM :

The strchr subroutine returns a pointer to the first occurrence of the character specified by the Character **(converted to an unsigned character)** parameter in the string pointed to by the String parameter. A null pointer is returned if the character does not occur in the string. The null byte that terminates a string is considered to be part of the string.

The strrchr subroutine returns a pointer to the last occurrence of the character specified by the Character **(converted to a character)** parameter in the string pointed to by the String parameter. A null pointer is returned if the character does not occur in the string. The null byte that terminates a string is considered to be part of the string.

Comment: `strchr("Bananna", 'n')` vs. `strrchr("Bananna", 'n')` should illustrate the difference.

Comment: Why are you reading this IBM manual instead of the php.net manual? Do you have a link to the IBM manual you are referring to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`strchr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strchr.php) is an alias of [`strstr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php):

> Returns part of haystack string starting from and including the **first
>   occurrence** of needle to the end of haystack.

[`strrchr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php):

> This function returns the portion of haystack which starts at the **last
>   occurrence** of needle and goes until the end of haystack.

`strchr` starts at the first occurrence, `strrchr` starts at the last occurrence.

Comment: I ended up doing it like so and it worked :                    `code`$trim = substr(strrchr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], "/"), 1); `code`

Comment: For strrchr, only the first character in $needle is used. strrchr("example_example_extra", "example") will return "extra" and not "example_extra"

Answer (score 9):

[`strchr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) finds the first occurrence and [`strrchr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) (r - reverse) finds the last occurrence of a character or string

```
$s = 'This is a test';
$first = strchr($s, 's');
$last = strrchr($s, 's');
```

- `$first` contains `s is a test`
- `$last` contains `st`